# document.execCommand('copy') scrolls to bottom in IE and Edge

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am using the `copyToClipboard` in my application. It works good in Chrome and Firefox browsers except in IE and Firefox.

In **I.E.** *(esp. version 11)*, on click of *Copy*, it introduces a native browser popup, asking to Allow or Deny and also it **scrolls** to bottom of the page.

The popup introduction is fine, but I **need to stop** the scrolling downwards.

**Code:**

```
$scope.copyData = function(id) {
    var copyAreaObject = document.createElement('textarea');
    $scope.copyInitialize(id, copyAreaObject);
    var selector = document.querySelector('#copyWrapper');
    selector.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
    document.body.removeChild(copyAreaObject);
  };
```

[**Click Here for Demo**](https://plnkr.co/edit/szOb8xDM3Jm8B4l1kiLG?p=preview)

Comment: Your appending your textbox to the end of the body. I guess the browser scrolls down to the element that is being copied so the user can see what they are adding to the clipboard.

Comment: @ste2425 I am creating `textarea` and not `textbox`, that too dynamically. I don't think scrolling issue is due to that.

Answer (score 7):

Tried Deigo Plutino's answer with additional properties as shown below:

```
copyAreaObject.style.position = 'fixed';
copyAreaObject.style.bottom= 0;
copyAreaObject.style.left= 0;
```

It works fine and prevents the scrolling issue. Tested in Edge and IE 11.

For more info, you can also refer to this post: [How do I copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

A simple workaround is setting the style "position" of the textarea to "fixed", so IE doesn't need to scroll.

```
copyAreaObject.style.position = "fixed";
```

Comment: Works fine after setting top/bottom and left/right values along with position: 'fixed'.